# Is the "for" in "for too long" necessary?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say:

> The night she passed away, I sat in front of the TV too long.

Or must I say

> The night she passed away, I sat in front of the TV for too long.

Comment: Like the _for_ that marks the subject of an infinitive clause (_For him to leave now would be a mistake_), this _for_ is only necessary when beginning a sentence. _For too long we have accepted this_, but not **Too long we have accepted this*.

Comment: They're both acceptable reductions of 'for too long a time'; the shorter one is probably more idiomatic (popular).

Comment: @JohnLawler Actually, I think _Too long have we accepted this_ would be ok - don't you?

Comment: Yes, but that requires subject-verb inversion. Different structure, different rule.

Comment: @JohnLawler, it’s 2:30 AM here, so perhaps my brain is not functioning quite properly … but when can the _for_ that marks the subject of an infinitive clause be dropped when not sentence-initial? “It would be a mistake for him to leave now” still requires it, as do all other constructions I can think of … (Also, “Too long we have accepted this” sounds just as fine to me as “For too long we have accepted this”—both being significantly inferior and less natural than the inverted form.)

Comment: With B-Raising, for instance: _I expect him to leave soon_ is only dialectally _I expect for him to leave soon_. Also with B-Equi: _I told him to leave now_ deletes the _for_ subject marker along with the coreferential subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions are correct, though the shorter one (*'too long'*) might seem a bit more informal in some contexts.

In fact the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) contains hundreds of sentences that don't have a 'for' before the 'too long' (but in which you could add the 'for' if you wanted to), including:

> *The rest of the artifacts have been moldering in the ground **too long** for me to say what they are or to get anything off them.*
>
> *...his eyes were so blue that they left her feeling as though she'd stared **too long** up into the sky.*
>
> *The bullet is for himself, if the bear mauling drags on **too long**.*